# \d versus [0-9] in .NET regular expressions

Tags: .net, regex

I often see `[0-9]` used in .NET regular expression answers on Stack Overflow instead of `\d`. I’ve asked why, and the answer tends to be “`\d` matches more than just `[0-9]`”. So what more does it match? [This table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#code-snippet-1) says it matches decimal digits. And what about `\p{Nd}`?

Or is there no difference, and this is just good practice because of some other regex engine?

Comment: I would guess `\p{Nd}` matches [these](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is also in the [linked reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#code-snippet-1):

> \d matches any decimal digit. It is equivalent to the \p{Nd} regular
>   expression pattern, which includes the standard decimal digits 0-9 **as
>   well as the decimal digits of a number of other character sets**.

So `\d` can match things like decimal digits in the Arabic character set, which wouldn't be matched with `[0-9]`.

Comment: Wow, I can’t believe I didn’t see that section while finding http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories. Thanks.