# How to get a date and count elements from a string?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following String

```
 String str1 =   "Peter L. Douglas 04/02/1984 X1 X5 YY" ;
```

I need to get three separate strings as following

```
String str1_name = "Peter L. Douglas" ;
String str1_date = "04/02/1984" ;
String str1_nbr  = "3"  ;     // 3 is three elements after date , i.e. X1 X5 YY
```

I am not sure how I could do this in the most efficient way , especially counting the elements after the date

---

Other possible   Strings are

`String str1 =   "Alexander Evanston 05/02/1986 X5 YY" ;`

Comment: What is the actual pattern of your strings? Will trailing elements always be two characters?  You have not provided enough information.

Answer (score 3):

To obtain the three parts from your string, you can use

```
^([A-Za-z. ]+) ((?:[0-9]{2}/){2}[0-9]{4}) (.*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/H3ESMquXuHYehq_d)

The name is is capture group 1, the date in 2, the "X" pieces in 3. This regex assumes the date is always valid. If you really need to ensure a proper date, you can read [*this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22131040/2736496) I wrote about using regex to validate numeric ranges.

Also note that while you could use `\d` in place of `[0-9]`, `[0-9]` is more universal, as `\d` can capture non-american numbers in .NET for example. More information [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9) and [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194645/d-versus-0-9-in-net-regular-expressions).

---

To get the number of "X" pieces, just split group three, and then count the resulting array elements:

```
int xPieceCount = matcher.group(3).split(" ").length();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

Find the date pattern(DD/MM/YYYY) first then get others also as simple as it is.

```
    String str1 = "Peter L. Douglas 04/02/1984 X1 X5 YY";
    Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d/\\d\\d/\\d\\d\\d\\d");

    Matcher m = pt.matcher(str1);

    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(str1.substring(0, m.start()).trim());
        System.out.println(m.group());
        System.out.println(str1.substring(m.end()).trim().split("\\s+").length);
    }
```

output

```
Peter L. Douglas
04/02/1984
3
```

Comment: Interesting idea to anchor the logic on a single date-regex. +1