# Regular expression to match a non-zero, zero-padded integer

Tags: regex

I need help with a pattern to match a zero-padded integer which is not all zeros.  It can have zero to n leading zeros.  So far I have:

```
^[0-9]{0,}[1-9]{1}$"
```

but this does not get things like `000860` because of the last zero.  I feel like this should be simple, but I can't get it.  Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:  A few people have asked which engine/language this is.  I thought regex was standardized so it wouldn't matter.  But it's .NET.

Comment: Why not add `[0-9]{0,}` (or `[0-9]*`) right before the `$` as well? (BTW: you can omit the `{1}` as well, it's implicit).

Comment: @Wrikken -- because then `000000` would work.

Comment: No, because you still have that required `[1-9]` in there. So, a non-zero would be necessary.

Comment: Ahhh...you're right.  That works.

Comment: The other answers below are a little more efficient for the regex engine though ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not using this:

```
^0*[1-9][0-9]*$
```

? 
Btw, you missed to specify the regex engine in use. But the above pattern should work in almost any regex engine.

Comment: Why does `0*` work for the first zero(s) but not the last one?  In other words, why can't I do this: `^0*[1-9]0*$`?

Comment: Which programming language or regex engine are you using?

Comment: That will leave you with any number of zeros followed by a single positive integer followed by any number of zeros. You can tweak what you suggested by doing this:
    ^0*[1-9]*0*
but that will leave you with a regex that won't match something with a zero in the middle like this: 00342010. If you replace the ending 0* with \d* or [0-9]* then you should have what you want.

Comment: @S.C. Isn't `00100` or `001000` valid? Btw, what is the difference to your answer?

Comment: Yes, both of those are valid based on my interpretation of the question. If that's not what is wanted, then 0+ should replace 0* in the beginning.

Comment: @hek2mgl -- Yes `00100` and `001000` are valid.

Comment: @hek2mgl, the only difference is \d instead of the explicit [0-9] and mine was submitted a few seconds after yours.

Comment: Which is more efficient?

Comment: @roryap You can't do `^0*[1-9]0*` because this would mean: `0-x zeros`, `one number from 1 to 9`, `0-x zeros`. This would match only: `0100`, `00020`, `00001` but not `0110`

Comment: @hek2mgl -- yep, I see that now.

Comment: @roryap, just looked that up and learned something new. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194645/d-versus-0-9-in-net-regular-expressions Good question; thanks for asking.

Comment: @S.C. It looks like a communication error :). Your comment, the third one, just wasn't addressed to me but to the OP. +1 for your answer! even if it was given a second after mine.. (hihi :) )...

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.

Comment: Well, I wish I could accept multiple answers, but I'll have to go with efficiency :)  Thanks to all.

Comment: Good decision! :D thanks! Just one more thing: next time you are having a regex question, you should probably name the regex engine in your question. This is sometimes/mostly important because the syntax differs between them.

Answer (score 4):

Just try with following regex:

```
^0*[1-9][0-9]*$
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this regex?
`^0*[1-9]\d*$`

Answer (score 1):

Would you like to catch 860?

```
"000860".match(/^0*([1-9][0-9]*)$/)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but a little explanation would be good.

Comment: The parentheses are completely useless.. additionally you make assumptions about the language used, added no explantion whatsoever and didn't even provide a real regex, but an expression matching a constant string against a regex and returning the second match, which will throw an index out of range exception (or similar) -1

Comment: The regex is actually usable. But! .NET matches the regex to strings: `new Regex("/^0*[1-9][0-9]*$/").Matches("000860");`  would thus be correct. This btw returns a result of type `Match`. My point holds, your answer deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Well here's my take:

`0+[1-9]+[0-9]{0,}`

it captures at least one zero (append `?` after the first `0` instead of `+`, if its possible to have no leading zeroes), at least one non-zero number then any number of zeroes and other digits.

and if you want to capture the number without the zeroes:

`0+([1-9]+[0-9]{0,})`

which simply places the part after the leading zeroes in a capture group.

[play with it here](http://regex101.com/r/bN0fU0/4)

parses all of these successfully:

```
000860
000860123
000800
000810
0008
```